# Help with NGINX conf for reverse proxy for both WSS to ws and HTTPS to http, Debian 11, looping redirects

Tags: debian, nginx, reverse-proxy

My current config for NGINX results in infinite loop of redirects to https, when I try to access index.html. Does someone have the correct way to do this?

The goal is to forward inbound requests on port 443 that are for starting a WSS connection to a WS connection at localhost on the same port. Also, to forward requests on port 443 that are for web files, to localhost port 80.

Here is the redirecting conf (which is placed in /etc/nginx/conf.d/myFQDN.conf

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}

upstream to-websocket {
    server localhost:25565;
}

server_tokens off;

# SSL requirements. We use Certbot and LetsEncrypt
#ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/-myFQDN-/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
#ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/-myFQDN-/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
#include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
#ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
#ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;

#ssl_session_timeout 5m;
#ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

server {
#   first redirect to https
    if ($scheme = "http") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

#   Now webserver
#   Port 80 shouldn't be accesed from outside
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name -myFQDN- www.-myFQDN-;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
    root /var/www/html;
}

server {
    root /var/www/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    server_name -myFQDN-;

#   Proxy our outside https to local http
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/-myFQDN-/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/-myFQDN-/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        try_files /nonexistent @$http_upgrade;
    }
    location @websocket {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host -myFQDN-;
        proxy_set_header Referer https://-myFQDN-;
        proxy_set_header Referrer https://-myFQDN-;
#       proxy_pass http://localhost:25565;
        proxy_pass http://to-websocket;
    }

    location @ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host -myFQDN-;
        proxy_set_header Referer https://-myFQDN-;
        proxy_set_header Referrer https://-myFQDN-;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:80;
    }
}
```

Comment: I discovered the commenting out the location@ prox_pass stops the looping. However the WSS to WS doesn't work.

Comment: I tried changing this quite a lot, but still don't have it working. Within the 443 server, I'm using ' location / {
        try_files $uri /static/ @wss;
    }' and have define the location @wss {} However don't seem to get any logging about WSS even at debug level.